# タグ [vb.net], [vba], [vbs] のデフォルトハイライト表示を lang-vb にしたい

Tags: 機能の要求, シンタックスハイライト

タグ [vb.net](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net), [vba](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba), [vbs](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vbs) をプログラミング言語に関係するものだと設定し、その上でシンタックスハイライトのデフォルトを `lang-vb` に設定したいです。現状では、そもそもハイライトの設定リスト自体が無いです。

参考: 本家 Stack Overflow において対応するタグでは、どれも `lang-vb` に設定されています。

- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vb.net/info
- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vba/info
- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vbscript/info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

いずれも `lang-vb` に変更しておきました。